# python logging - redirect the log to different file based on the log message

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

The application use python logging. It has different module and each module has a logger, with root at the top hierarchy. There is three module which communicate with the 3rd party API. Tracking log of request/response from the third party API is time consuming. So based on log message, the redirection of log to different log file is required. This will simplify the API request/response log tracking. The redirection of log based on the log level is quite common but I am not able to come up with an efficient design to redirect the API specific log to different log file based on the log message content. Below is an approached which can be used to achieved the requirement.

```
class APILevelLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
    def emit(self, record):
        import re, os, socket
        logFileList = []
        matchObj = re.search('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', str(record.msg))
    logPath = "/tmp/"
    try:
        if matchObj and socket.inet_aton(matchObj.group()):
            if not matchObj.group() in logFileList:
                logFileList.append(matchObj.group())
                if not os.path.isdir(logPath):
                    try:
                        os.makedirs(logPath)
                    except OSError:
                        print "Exception", ex, callstack.ExcepCallStack()
            if "dataReceived" in record.msg or "send" in record.msg:
                with open(str(os.path.join(logPath, matchObj.group()+".log")), 'a') as f:
                    f.write(record.msg + '\n')
    except Exception, ex:
        print "Exception", ex, callstack.ExcepCallStack()
```

During the python logging setup of application, the handler is added to the root logger as

```
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.addHandler(APILevelLogHandler())

Output.log
API test1 1.1.1.1 data send
API test2 2.2.2.2 data send
API test1 1.1.1.1 data received
API test1 1.1.1.1 data send
API test2 2.2.2.2 data received
API test1 1.1.1.1 data received

Expected output
1.1.1.1.log
API test1 1.1.1.1 data send
API test1 1.1.1.1 data received
API test1 1.1.1.1 data send
API test1 1.1.1.1 data received

2.2.2.2.log
API test2 2.2.2.2 data send
API test2 2.2.2.2 data received
```

Please suggest me a better design to achieved the above requirement.

Thanks,
Ranjan

One more probable solution:

Above approached will add an extra overhead to the existing process and if I want to use the same functionality provided by the handler RotatingFileHandler, then I have to rewrite the functionality. So I have one more suggestion which work well if the logging is done from one module, but in my case the logging is done from multiple module. So I need to redirect the log from common logging setup. Please let me know if there is any other possible way for multiple module.

```
    logFileName = "logFileName_extracted_from_message"
    self.apilevelLogger = logging.getLogger(logFileName)
    if any(isinstance(item, logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) for item in logging.getLogger('').handlers):
        handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logFileName, maxBytes=10e6, backupCount=3)
        self.apilevelLogger.addHandler(handler)
        self.apilevelLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    self.apilevelLogger.info("API test1 1.1.1.1 send data")
```

In second approached, the no. of logger created is equal to no. of log file created. Instead of adding the same code to all the module, I hope there is room for further improvement. Please help to improved the efficiency and design.

Thanks,
Ranjan

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (simplified script structure):

```
def writelog(text, file):
    # simplified version
    filehandle = open(file, 'a') # 'a' for 'append'
    filehandle.write(text)
    filehandle.close()

# (...) will be the group(1) of the match and the filename
matchObj = re.search('(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', str(record.msg))
filename = matchObj.group(1)

# perform further tests to see if you want to write the message to the log
if ... :
    writelog(record.msg, filename)
```

Does that help ?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt useful reply. Further I would like to know whether the redirection of log based on log message should be done from the Handler.

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code, so it's hard to say. As far as I can see there is nothing against putting those lines of code in the handler.

Comment: I have one more solution, Please provide your valuable inputs. ranjan

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this [python log router](https://github.com/IBM/python-log-router) library. Maybe it fits your scenario. This library lets you route logs based on a discriminator (an extra field in the LogRecord object).